# Data-driven styling in Mapbox GL JS - Error when drawing circle radius by zoom level and property

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm playing around with [data-driven styling](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/data-driven-styling/) in Mapbox GL JS.  Setting the circle color based on a layer property works just fine:

`"circle-color": {
     'property': 'mag',
     'stops': [
       [4, "hsl(0, 100%, 50%)"],
       [8, "hsl(60, 100%, 50%)"]
     ]
 }`

But when I try to set the circle radius by property and zoom like this:

```
"circle-radius": {
    'property': 'mag',
    'stops': [
        [{zoom: 4, value: 4}, 2],
        [{zoom: 4, value: 8}, 6],
        [{zoom: 12, value: 4}, 14],
        [{zoom: 12, value: 8}, 55]
     ]
 },
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: layers.earthquakes.paint.circle-radius.stops[0][0]: number expected, object found(…)   map.js:906
```

Is this just a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think mapbox watches Stackoverflow better, can you ask there?